# See metadata variable names on files (Windows 10)

Tags: powershell, windows-10, metadata, file-extension

I am having a hard time defining this issue, but basically what I would like to know is "what are the symbolic variable names connected to files' metadata (preferably on a Windows installation)".
For example, taking a `.mp3` file, checking its properties yields a Title, Bit Rate, Folder Path etc. descriptions. What I want to know is the name of the fields seen by programs (i.e. Title->title, Bit Rate->bit_rate etc.) if it makes any sense, as I've been trying to index some files and I'd like to gather as much info on them as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that there is such a thing as "symbolic names" for the metadata, especially not in relation to PowerShell. I suspect that Windows maintains support for a certain number of popular formats, and offers functionality through Explorer to view and sometimes edit them. I haven't found a source to prove this theory, but research implicitly supports it: there's several dozen search results about how to retrieve a file's metadata in PowerShell, and they all seem to suggest roughly the same approach (for example [this blog post](https://herringsfishbait.com/2015/04/03/powershell-getting-all-file-metadata-from-a-folder/)): using a Shell object to gather the information.

Since you tagged this PowerShell, here's my take on boiling it down to the essentials:

```
$path = 'C:\temp\file.txt' # pick a path
$parent = Split-Path -Parent $path # get the directory
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application # get ourselves a shell
$folder = $shell.NameSpace($parent) # get a "folder namespace"
$file = $Folder.Items() | where { $_.Path -eq $path } # get the file itself from the folder
$count = 0 # zero our iterator
$object = New-Object PSObject # make a fresh object to hold our output
While ($folder.GetDetailsOf($folder.Items, $count) -ne "") { # iterate over the available metadata tags for the folder, and for each one get the value from the file
    $object | Add-Member -Force NoteProperty ($folder.GetDetailsOf($folder.Items, $count)) ($folder.GetDetailsOf($file, $count))
    $count += 1
}
Write-Output $object
```

Note that the attributes available for a given file are obviously not all of the attributes that could possibly be supported for any file, and additionally are not necessarily "symbolic names". I suspect that the process of querying the shell object causes it to examine the files in a folder and extract metadata that Windows recognizes--it might even do this based on the view type selected for the folder (Photos, Music, Documents, etc.).

As for writing the information, this might be possible through the same shell object, but I haven't explored that option. It's likely dependent on the specific format: for mp3 you probably want a library for viewing/editing mp3-specific metadata.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I guess it was more like my question was badly posed. Thanks a lot, anyhow, this seems useful for other things I wanted to do ad well. I guess it's kind of hard to explain what I was looking for clearly, as it's more of a nutch-dependent problem, but I think I can work with this.